# PHP file upload failure for large files

Tags: file-upload, nginx, php

I am using a slightly modified version of [phUploader](http://www.phphq.net/scripts.php?download=phUploader) script that works fine for small files. But when I try to upload files larger than 1MB it fails by giving this undescriptive error:

```
General upload failure.
```

Nginx error log does not show any evidence. I have set

```
upload_max_filesize = 200M
post_max_size = 200M
memory_limit = 128M
```

in the php.ini

and

```
client_max_body_size 200M;
```

in nginx.conf.

The odd thing is that the script used to work well on the same server (before an upgrade on Debian 6  server) and already works well on another Debian 6 server with the same nginx and php configs. So I'm really out of ideas and appreciate your hints.

Comment: having the similar issue, have u found the cause?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're getting an undescriptive error because the script you're using isn't properly displaying the actual error (line 252).

Modify the script to echo or log the value of `$_FILES['file']['error']` instead of "General upload failure." Then, you should see a more appropriate error code. The PHP Manual has a [section](http://www.php.net/manual/en/features.file-upload.errors.php) that explains what the error codes mean.